# How to include a template variable in a MediaWiki extension tag?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to invoke this tag from within a template:

```
<splist
 parent={{{1}}}
 showparent=no
 showpath=no
 kidsonly=yes
 liststyle=bar
 debug=1
/>
```

As you can see a template variable needs to be filled in here. But unfortunately MW does not do that.

My question: How to accomplish this? How do I need to call the extension in order to get the variable data filled into parameter `parent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `{{#tag:}}` parser function:

```
{{#tag:splist
 | parent={{{1}}}
 | showparent=no
 | showpath=no
 | kidsonly=yes
 | liststyle=bar
 | debug=1
}}
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Miscellaneous.

Comment: Whoa thanx! I'm wondering why I was NOT able to find that though I did an extensive search with Google. I'll try your recommendation ASAP ...

Comment: Thank you very much!